# Disable Action Buttons Conditionally (AEF)

Tags: acumatica

If I have an Action button added on a Graph, how can I programmatically control whether it is enabled or disabled? For example, if I want to disable the button, related to a particular field in my Main DAC, how should I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the DACs row selected you can call on your action SetEnabled to indicate if the button is enabled or not.

Example:

```
protected virtual void MyDac_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    myButtonAction.SetEnabled(true /*false*/);
}

public PXAction<MyDac> myButtonAction;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Button", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false)]
[PXButton]
public virtual IEnumerable MyButtonAction(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    reteurn adapter.Get();
}
```